# AfxGetModuleState returns value that has different address in releasewithdebug

Tags: c++, mfc, embedded-resource

I have convenient class that switches between different dlls in which I store resources. Each dll registers itself (instance and other infos) using its `enum` value. The infos are stored in static fields. When I need to switch the resource handle I use constructor with specific module `enum` value which switches current resource handle and saves old resource handle.

The situation is as follows. I get current module state with `AfxGetModuleState` in a dll with algorithm then use my convenient class to switch resource handle to a dll with resources, then I again use `AfxGetModuleState` in the dll with algorithm. The address of the structure returned by `AfxGetModuleState` in the dll with algorithm and in my convenient class is **different**.

My application is single-threaded thus address of the structure returned by `AfxGetModuleState` must be the same (it has to be global), but it is **different**.

This causes resources from a specific dll unable to load because the current resouce handle which was set in my convenient class to a dll with resources remains null in dll with algorithm and `CString::LoadString(nID)` fails.

The debug version of my application works well, but the error appears only in `releasewithdebug`.

PS: I'm a novice MFC programmer.

Comment: I assume you mean AfxGetStaticModuleState()? Where is your convenience class? In the dll or in your main app?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, it is in another dll. I use exactly AfxGetModuleState() and switch the structure's m_hCurrentResourceHandle and m_hCurrentInstanceHandle fields to a specific module handle.